# DataTable and LazyDataModel not calling load

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, seam, lazydatamodel

I am Using `primefaces 6.0` with `seam 2.2` and `jsf 2.2`, trying to get the `lazydatamodel` working on a `p:dataTable`.

I have created my own LazyDataType specific to the entity in the datable and defined a load override method in the class.

The table is rendered correctly but i have to manually set first page of results when initialising it, the load method never gets fired on the table update.

I have noticed that when running through the Primefaces `DataTable.class` in debug it encounters the - `loadLazyData()` - method in this the correct model is found which is of my extended class of the `lazyDataModel` type but when it gets to this line `if(model != null && model instanceof LazyDataModel)` 
it returns `false`.

The model object is definitely not null and my of the type of my class extending the `LazyDataModel` type so this should return true

I am guessing this is why the load method doesn’t fire…

Has any one encountered this issue? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

My extended class is shown below

```
public class CompetitionUserLazyDataModel extends LazyDataModel<CompetitionUser>{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5634037604279083091L;

private Competition competition;

public CompetitionUserLazyDataModel(){

}

public CompetitionUserLazyDataModel(Competition competition, int rowCount){
    this.setCompetition(competition);
    super.setRowCount(rowCount);
    super.setRowIndex(0);
    super.setPageSize(5);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public CompetitionUser getRowData(String rowKey) {
   List<CompetitionUser> data = (List<CompetitionUser>) super.getWrappedData();   
   return data.get(Integer.parseInt(rowKey));
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public Object getRowKey(CompetitionUser competitionUser) {
   List<CompetitionUser> data = (List<CompetitionUser>) super.getWrappedData();  
   return data.indexOf(competitionUser);
}

@Override
public List<CompetitionUser> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField,
   SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, Object> filters) {

   CompetitionUserDAO competitionUserDAO = (CompetitionUserDAO)Component.getInstance("competitionUserDAO");
   List<CompetitionUser> results = competitionUserDAO.getLazyListOfCompetionUsersForCompetetion(this.competition, first, pageSize);
   this.setWrappedData(results);
   this.setRowCount(this.competition.getNoCompetitors());
   return results;
}   

 public Competition getCompetition() {
    return competition;
 }

 public void setCompetition(Competition competition) {
    this.competition = competition;
 }
}
```

Comment: are you sure it is the same instance of the model when the new request is send?

Comment: @Kukeltje Hi, yes I believe so i have debugged using eclipse as much as possible and everything seems to be set correctly... this is why i'm not sure what is going on